# Alternatives to Wakelocks?

Tags: android, multithreading, cpu, sleep, wakelock

I'm working on an app which needs to send data to a webserver after every x minutes (where x is a value that can be changed through webserver responses).

Right now, I'm using a background thread that sleeps for x minutes and then notifies the main thread to start sending data.

However, I'm experiencing issues with this method due to CPU-sleeping, which seems to affect the thread sleeping time.

I've read about wakelocks and think I could implement a partial wakelock...however, one of the core features of this app is to save battery, so overall wakelocks just aren't feasible.

So I was wondering if there are any alternatives to wakelocks that can make sure that a certain piece of logic always runs in the background after every x minutes, ideally only waking up the CPU when it is needed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the AlarmManager to set hard intervals. It will wake up the device if the device is sleeping. While your app does its thing grab a wakelock so that the device doesn't fall asleep and release it after you are done

Answer (score 2):

Use [`SheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) for this. It can handle single tasks, periodic tasks etc...