# Xamarin wakelock

Tags: xamarin, android-wake-lock

I use PowerManager.WakeLock in my project to keep running my app in sleep mode, it is working great but this consumes a lot of energy and the device gets hot. What else should I do to keep my app running without a lot of energy?

My codes

```
PowerManager.WakeLock wakelock = default;
PowerManager pmanager = (PowerManager)GetSystemService("Power");
            wakelock = pmanager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "test");
            wakelock.SetReferenceCounted(false);
            wakelock.Acquire();
```

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940075/alternatives-to-wakelocks

Comment: @Amogh Sarpotdar thanks